# Downloading Tutorial

Tags: ros, arduino#ros#raspberry, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Im running ROS Kinetic on Raspbian with a RPI 3 and Im having trouble installing the kinetic tutorials, specifically this step from the wiki (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/NavigatingTheFilesystem):

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-<distro>-ros-tutorials
```

I am running it as

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials
```

But get the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-ros-tutorial
```

Does anybody have an idea of what am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244817/downloading-tutorial/) by [anonymous28122](https://answers.ros.org/users/28122/anonymous28122/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How did you install on the Raspbian? I did a compile from scratch on Jessie on Pi and for installing extra packages there is a process with it, vs using apt.

---

Originally posted by [mr337](https://answers.ros.org/users/27943/mr337/) with karma: 58 on 2016-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous28122](https://answers.ros.org/users/28122/anonymous28122/) on 2016-09-30**:
Hi!

I followed these steps:

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

I think it is installed properly since the enviroment variables are properly set and that's the way this group of steps begin.

**Comment by [mr337](https://answers.ros.org/users/27943/mr337/) on 2016-10-04**:
As tfoote mentioned, you should have used http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi. If so see section 4.2 Adding Released Packages

**Comment by [anonymous28122](https://answers.ros.org/users/28122/anonymous28122/) on 2016-10-05**:
Got it. I ran those as
pi@dex:~/ros_catkin_ws $ rosinstall_generator ros_tutorials --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar > kinetic-custom_ros.rosinstall and then all of the other spaces. So just to check, apt-get will not work?

**Comment by [mr337](https://answers.ros.org/users/27943/mr337/) on 2016-10-05**:
I don't see how, you are installing from source.